# How to make react table cell components communicate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a react table in my application:

[image]

As seen in the screenshot, it has two columns, one with input field and other is a normal div showing text.I would like to update the value of column 2 with value entered in column 1.

I am stuck with this, how can this be done in React?

Thanks

Update:
**Code of my table component:**

```
export default class customTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tableLoading: true,
            tabledata: [{override:80,final:90},{override:180,final:190}],
            tablelength: 0
        };
    }

    render() {

        const columns = [ {
            Header: props => <span>Override Value</span>,
            accessor: 'override',
            Cell: props => <input type="number"/>
        },
            {
                Header: 'Final',
                accessor: 'final'
            }];

        return (
                <ReactTable data={ this.state.tabledata } loading={ this.state.tableLoading } columns={ columns } defaultPageSize={ 12 } filterable={ true }
                  showPagination={ false } className="-striped -highlight fontsize-12" />
              );
    }
}
;
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried? are you using `state` ?

Comment: Added code of the component, @azium

Comment: ok, can you also provide a concrete example of what should happen? like "If I put the number 10 in the first input box on the left, the value on the right should be <value>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. It should be enough to get you started

- Add an `onChange` function to the `<input>` component in the first column (we'll call it `overrideValue`)
- From that function, update the `override` value of `this.state.tabledata` at the appropriate index. Also set a new value `overridden` to `true`
- In the second column, display the `override` value if `overridden == true`

  ```
  class customTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
          tableLoading: true,
          tabledata: [{override:80,final:90},{override:180,final:190}],
          tablelength: 0
      };
  }

  overrideValue = (index, override) => {
      let tabledata = [...this.state.tabledata]
      tabledata[index].override = override
      tabledata[index].overridden = true
      this.setState({ tabledata })
  }

  render() {

      const columns = [ 
          {
              Header: props => <span>Override Value</span>,
              accessor: 'override',
              Cell: props => <input onChange={e => this.overrideValue(props.index, e.target.value)} type="number"/>
          },
          {
              Header: 'Final',
              accessor: 'final',
              Cell: props => (props.original.overridden) ? props.original.override : props.original.final
          }
      ];

      return (
              <ReactTable data={ this.state.tabledata } loading={ this.state.tableLoading } columns={ columns } defaultPageSize={ 12 } filterable={ true }
                showPagination={ false } className="-striped -highlight fontsize-12" />
            );
  }
  };
  ```